# sql project aid required

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to generate a trigger that if a column within a table is filled in with a specific set value e.g. i have a column named 'Volunteertype' which can only be assigned either 'staff' of 'student', if student is entered the trigger must nullify all  columns relating to staff details within the volunteer table such as 'area of work', 'staffmanager' etc below is code i have tried to put together utilising the resources on the website however i'm having no luck.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_voltype
ON Volunteer
AFTER INSERT
AS 
IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM inserted i WHERE VolunteerType = 'student')
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN;
UPDATE v
SET Area_of_work       = NULL
SET StaffManagerName   = NULL
SET StaffManagerEmail  = NULL
SET StaffManagerPhone  = NULL
FROM Volunteer v
JOIN inserted i ON v.Volunteer_id = i.Volunteer_id
WHERE v.VolunteerType = 'student';
END;
```

However when this is run within the Oracle environment an error is produced ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword. when i attempt to shift the 'AFTER INSERT' to before the keyword i get an 'invalid trigger' error

Is anyone able to assist and inform me if the code itself is correct/ incorrect and how i should go about amending the code, thanks in advance and have a wonderful end to the year thanks!

Comment: I removed mysql tag

Comment: Have a look at the [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.htm#LNPLS01374)

Comment: Your trigger is completely malformed; but so is your update (you can't have a join; you have multiple `set` clauses...) - and you shouldn't be updating the row you just created anyway, you should adjust the values in a before-update trigger. Is `inserted` a separate table, or are you trying to refer to the new row's values? I'd suggest you go back to the documentation to try to create something closer to valid, and see what you're really stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger should be like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_voltype
  BEFORE INSERT ON volunteer
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if :new.Volunteertype = 'STUDENT'
  then
     :new.Area_of_work := NULL;
     :new.StaffManagerName := NULL;
     :new.StaffManagerEmail := NULL;
     :new.StaffManagerPhone := NULL ;
   end if;  

END;
```

Comment: Thnx @Alex Poole for quick fix here.